# HTTP Status 404 - /EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

Trying to make simple web app using Spring MVC. In which I am trying to submit information of Employees and it should show me message that Information submitted. But, It shows 404 error as following:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee
type Status report
message /EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
```

1) This is EmployeeController.java  :-

```
package com.SpringMVC.Employees;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class EmployeesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView employee() {
        return new ModelAndView("employee", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("SpringMVC_EmployeesInfoSubmitPg")Employee employee, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", employee.getName());
        model.addAttribute("age", employee.getAge());
        model.addAttribute("id", employee.getId());
        return "result";
    }
}
```

2) In Employee.java, I simply defined private fields of name, age and id and defined getters and setters methods for private fields.

3)This is web.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVC form of Employees Info.</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeInfoSubmitPg</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EmployeeInfoSubmitPg</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

4) This is EmployeeInfoSubmitPg-servlet.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringMVC.Employees" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

5) This is employee.jsp :-

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>SpringMVC form of Employees Info.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

6) This is result.jsp :-

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>SpringMVC form of Employees Info.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted Employee Information</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>${age}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>${id}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

- It was running fine half way when I entered as http://localhost:90/SpringMVC_EmployeeInfoPg/employee
  and after this it was showing error of HTTP Status 404 - /EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee
- But, now Eclipse is showing error on employee.jsp for this,
- it says  Missing end tag for "form:form"
- But, I closed it in employee.jsp
- Also, I forgot to mention that I took the example from 
  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm
- I just changed names of my project, package and other files.

Comment: Did u add @Component annotation in your Employee class

Comment: And is your jsp file in WEB-INF folder or  it is in some other folder

Comment: Is it WEB-INF/result.jsp or /WEB-INF/SomeFolder/result.jsp

Comment: no, I didn't add @Componenet annotation in Employee class.

Comment: jsp file is in WEB-INF folder...  so, it's WEB-INF/result.jsp

Comment: Use @Component annotation in employee class

Comment: I used @Component annotation in Employee.java class. It gave the same error. HTTP Status 404 - /EmployeeInfoSubmitPg/addEmployee

Comment: Your @ModelAttribute looks incorrect , it should be @ModelAttribute("employee")

Comment: I changed it to @ModelAttribute("employee"). Nothing happened. Same error again :(

Comment: form:form method="POST" action="./addEmployee"> , change ur form like this

Comment: Also in the above form:form tag define commandName="employee" attribute

Comment: Wowww... It worked like a charm... :) couldn't believe that I got the answer I was looking for since 3 days. Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help. :) I changed to
form:form method="POST" action="./addEmployee">  and got the answer.  But, I don't know what was the exact problem.

Comment: Cool please vote for my answer to earn me repo points, good luck

Comment: I am sorry. I m new here. How do I vote for your answer? I don't see any option to vote.  Okay Now I got it. Voted for your answer.. :)

Comment: On my answer u can see 0 with one arrow up and one down, u can vote by pressing up arrow and then selecting a tick box below to mark answer complete, green tick will appear to mark ur question as answered

Comment: I selected a tick box to mark answer is accepted and it shows green tick now. Also clicked on up arrow but I don't have 15 reputation. so, it says my vote will change publicly when I will earn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

form:form method="POST" action="./addEmployee"> , change ur form like this